# Logging and graphing the highest load average processes

Tags: ubuntu, server, collectd

Hey I'm running a Ubuntu server and have about 10 various services served from it. I currently use collectd combined with influxdb and graphana to create graphs of various server metrics including load average. Now I am seeing what looks like random cpu spikes and I want to see what process is causing them. What would be the easiest way to say graph the 10 highest load average processes so I could just hover over a point in time and clearly see what process was hogging the CPU?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution to your problem: write a script that generates a list of top processes, then trigger that script using a collectd notification, for instance when load/load-relative is over a threshold.